# How to remove plastic junction box

Tags: light-fixture

Does anyone know how to remove this type of junction box from the ceiling from underneath?[image]

Comment: Would it bother you too much to put a coverplate over the box?

Comment: I guess you are removing all the wiring too in order to meet code requirements that joins in wiring be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments everyone. I'm actually trying to remove the plastic junction box and keep the wiring to install a 6" recessed light there due to the limited amount of lighting in the area.

Answer (score 3):

It probably has wings with framing nails in them, like this:

[image]

You can either try sliding a saw through the gap outside the box and cutting the wings off, or you can cut up and remove the box a piece at a time. That's more difficult with plastic than with fiber, so be prepared for a battle. A rotary tool with a spiral cutter would work well.

If you're patching the drywall anyway, just put a block of wood in the box and drive it upward with a hammer.